# How to change the value of a boolean array that is called by a for loop parameter in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following problem:

Inside a for loop, I try to call an array that is from another class and I have it as public, through the parameter, when I want to assign a value to the parameter, it is not reflected in the array.

1). Is it the correct way to call the array using the parameter?

2). Where am I failing and why is the value "True" that I assign to the matrix not assigned?

```
static public void VentanaReserva(System.Windows.Forms.Button button , bool Valor1  )
        {
            if (Valor1 == false)
            {
                button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                Valor1 = true;     **//This is where you assign the value of true** -----

                MessageBoxBase messageBoxBase = new MessageBoxBase();

                messageBoxBase.ShowDialog();
                ValorCancha.SumaDeCanchaPequeña();

            }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//this is the place where I assign the parameters that are in another class
        {

            EstadoDeReserva.VentanaReserva(button1, ValorCancha.Visualizar[0,1]);
         }
```

Comment: You're passing `Valor1` by value, a new value assigned to it is not reflected in the collection. Does it matter? If this value is already `true`, nothing happens, if it's `false`, you appear to change it to `true`, so just change it to `true` anyway after you have called your method.

Comment: bool is a value type and will be copied when passed to another method. You need to use ref if you want to pass the reference to the value instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like this:

```
var myBools = new bool[10];
for(var i = 0; i < myBools.Length; i++){
    MyMethod(myBools[i]);
}
void MyMethod(bool myBool){
    myBool = !myBool;
}
```

This will not work since primitive types like bools are *passed by [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)*. So assigning a new value to any parameter will not affect the original value.

The easiest way to get around this is to just return the new value and assign it:

```
var myBools = new bool[10];
for(var i = 0; i < myBools.Length; i++){
    myBools[i] = MyMethod(myBools[i]);
}
bool MyMethod(bool myBool){
    return !myBool;
}
```

There is also the possibility to pass parameters by [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), as well as [ref return and ref local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns), but that is not something I would recommend unless you have some very specific use cases. Methods tend to be easiest to use if they take some parameters, return some value(s), and does not have any side effects.

Comment: Eres el mejor muchas gracias, me explicaste de la mejor manera lo que las otras buenas personas me dijeron , te quiero hermano :)))